# MYSQL I need some default if there is no result

Tags: mysql, select, return, is-empty, where-in

I have a table(currency_table) which has 3 columns "date","currency","rate".

and i have to query with syntax below

```sql
select date, rate from currency_table where date in ('20010101','20190921','20190920');
```

in table(currency_table), there is not data for 20010101

so i have result like 
2019-09-20   1200
2019-09-21   1200.1

but i have to have the return even "null" if  there is no value

how can i do this ???

and one more question

the result always display ordered by the date.

can i receive the result order by i wrote ?

Comment: 'how can i do this' do you have a calendar/dates table, what version of mysql are you on?. 'can i receive the result order by i wrote' what order would you like? What data type is your date column?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called a *calendar* table here, which keeps track of all dates which you want to appear in your reporting.  An example would be the best way to explain:

```
SELECT
    d.date,
    COALESCE(t.rate, 0.0) AS rate
FROM
(
    SELECT '2001-01-01' AS date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-09-21' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-09-20'
) d
LEFT JOIN currency_table t
    ON d.date = t.date AND
WHERE
    d.date IN ('2001-01-01', '2019-09-21', '2019-09-20')
ORDER BY
    d.date;
```

In practice, you would probably replace the subquery I have labelled as `d` with a bona-fide table containing all dates for which you might want to report currency rates.  Note that because I used a left join above, every date in the calendar table is guaranteed to appear in the result set.  However, for non matching dates, a rate of `0.0` would appear (which rate would probably never occur in the real world).

Comment: ? But the example doesn't use a calendar table !?! I'm confused

Comment: Yes, he didn't use but he mentioned it *you would probably replace the subquery I have labelled as d with a bona-fide table containing all dates*